# What is the difference of 'max_iter' definition for "LBFGS" and "SGD,Adam" optimizers in sklearn MLPClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, scikit-learn

I am trying to use [scikit-learn's MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) with the LBFGS optimizer to solve a classification problem. In the documentation of the module, there is a statement that `max_iter` determines the number of epochs (how many times each data point will be used), not the number of gradient steps. What does 'number of gradient steps' mean in this context, and what is the difference between "number of epochs" and "number of gradient steps"?

Answer (score 2):

`sklearn` provides *stochastic* optimizers for the MLP class like SGD or Adam and the *Quasi-Newton* method LBFGS.

Stochastic optimizers work on batches. They take a subsample of the data, evaluate the loss function and take a step in the opposite direction of the loss-gradient. This process is repeated until all data has been used. This is called an *epoch* or *how many times each data point is used*. Note that if you have 1000 data points and you make 10 batches of 100 points, you will make 10 gradient steps per epoch (or iteration).

Quasi-newton methods try to approximate the Hessian matrix in every step by using all the data (not batches). Therefore LBFGS will make a single gradient step per iteration.

By using stochastic optimizers you will make `batch_size`*`max_iter` more gradient steps as with the Quasi-Newton method. You'll further notice that the `batch_size` argument will not be used if `solver=lbfgs`.